# Trying to populate a listbox with xml data obtained from API

Tags: c#, xml, api, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Okay, here i am building this dictionary app for windows phone.It uses the merriam-webster api that returns a query as an xml. I am trying to populate this onto a longlist selector with the id from xml elements

This just throws a thread has exited with code 259 error and the list is empty. Please help on the matter.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wcXML = new WebClient();
        wcXML.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/medical/xml/" + MedSearch.Text + "?key=235089d7-eb18-47f6-9ab8-226685fc7d98"));
        wcXML.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void c_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            var s = e.Result;
            Debug.WriteLine(""+e.Result);
            var rssElement = XElement.Parse(s);
                            var items = from item in rssElement.Descendants("entry")
                          select new entry_list
                          {
                              id = item.Attribute("id").Value,
                              fl = item.Element("fl").Value,
                              def = item.Element("def").Element("sensb").Element("sens").Element("dt").Value

                          };

            listBox1.ItemsSource = items;

            //checking if anything is there.
            string result = "";

            foreach (entry_list i in items)
            {
                result += i.def;
            }
            resultsBlock.Text = result;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the sequence of your code as because event should be implemented before it invoked as well as if you are using event DownloadStringCompleted then you should call DownloadStringAsync not OpenReadAsync

```
            WebClient wcXML = new WebClient();
            wcXML.DownloadStringCompleted += wcXML_DownloadStringCompleted;
            wcXML.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/medical/xml/" + MedSearch.Text + "?key=235089d7-eb18-47f6-9ab8-226685fc7d98"));
```

Now if the MedSearch.Text is "her" then e.Result will be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entry_list version="1.0">
    <suggestion>hear</suggestion>
    <suggestion>Er</suggestion>
    <suggestion>ear</suggestion>
    <suggestion>aer-</suggestion>
    <suggestion>hair</suggestion>
    <suggestion>hour</suggestion>
    <suggestion>air</suggestion>
    <suggestion>Ar</suggestion>
    <suggestion>Ir</suggestion>
    <suggestion>OR</suggestion>
    <suggestion>hr</suggestion>
    <suggestion>ir-</suggestion>
    <suggestion>ur-</suggestion>
    <suggestion>hairy</suggestion>
    <suggestion>Haller</suggestion>
    <suggestion>hilar</suggestion>
    <suggestion>rheo-</suggestion>
    <suggestion>Re</suggestion>
    <suggestion>r</suggestion>
    <suggestion>Rh</suggestion>
</entry_list>
```

I think because key you have used is temporary that's why limited nodes and attributes is available
Now you can manipulate this data as per you requirement

Comment: oh that is because it returns results only for medical related queries, try nurse

Comment: ok i just checked, changing the sequence did help. I downloaded the xml and now gonna use it to populate the list after some refinements. thank you